# How do I convert this into math? "As the experiment repeats, the probability gets closer to $\frac{1}{3}$"

Tags: probability

Here's the experiment simulated https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/Bwvrwv

I know that the probability of a coin hitting heads after two rolls is $\frac{3}{4}$. I want to use the probability equation of a coin flipping to say that

"As the experiment repeats, the probability of heads approaches $\frac{1}{3}$" while the math should also say that if the experiment is performed one time, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$. Hopefully comp sci people and math people can team up to write the solution to this question lol. There's got to be a way to formulate the increase in probability over n tries and then set the limit to $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: It sounds like you might be asking for [the law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: You are talking about the [Sleeping Beauty problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty_problem). Make sure you make this clear in your question (instead of providing external links) and also please be clear about what you are asking, or at which point you are confused.

Comment: Would something like this work? ((n-1)/n)(1/3) + (1/2^n)(1/2) = P(heads)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to express it using mathematical notation:

> For the random variable $X$, where $X_n$ is the value of $X$ after $n$ trials:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {X_n \over n} = \frac 13$$

The validity of this statement follows from the Law of Large Numbers, as JMoravitz mentioned, and the statement is therefore synonymous with $E(X) = \frac 13$, where $E$ is the expected value of $X$.

Comment: I'm thinking of this in terms of a linear equation using neural networks... Couldn't it be modeled P(heads) = 1/3 * ((n-1)/n) + 1/2 (something)? Because when n equals 1, the coefficient is 0 * 1/3 = 0

Comment: I need an equation that = 0 when n is not equal to 1

Comment: I will point out that with $X$ as you have defined it you have not specified how many times she guesses in total and the probability could be zero.  If you specify that she guesses $n$ times as well, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(X=n)$ in fact approaches zero.  The more times she is asked to guess the less likely she will be to get every guess correct.  You mean to say that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_n}{n}=\frac{1}{3}$ where $X_n$ counts the number of successful guesses in $n$ attempts.

Comment: Gah, you're right. I shouldn't try to answer these questions when I'm as exhausted as I am. Thank you for catching that.